# rsync error: unexplained error (code 130 ) at rsync.c(543) [sender=3.0.7]

Tags: rsync

```
rsync error: unexplained error (code 130
) at rsync.c(543) [sender=3.0.7]
```

I am having this error on a companys machien. unfortunately i don't have the exact version right now because i am already at home.

Does anybody know in which cases rsync might return 130, and what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by the two separate error messages you posted, but loking at the first one, it seems to indicate that the error came from the rsync-3.0.7 running on the remote end.  Line 543 of rsync.c in v3.0.7 is:

```
exit_cleanup(RERR_SIGNAL);
```

so it looks like something on the remote end is causing an unexpected exit.

I suggest as a first step you upgrade to v3.0.7 on your machine and retry, to see if you get better diagnostic info.  Then, follow the [rsync debugging guide](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/issues.html) to track down the real failure.

Is the name of the file it aborts on really `[EMAIL PROTECTED]:/`?  That's a mighty weird filename.  I'd first suspect that is causing the failure.

Comment: sorry i was confused too. mixed up my clip boards. the text below the escaped message was actually something i came across googling for the problem (unsucessfully). i tend to write my posts in a text editor first and then paste them... didnt look at it again after pasting. thanks for your answer it helps. will correct the question.